# Geometric probability: Estimating regions devoid of random points

Tags: real-analysis, probability, limits, analysis, geometric-probability

First, generate $N$ random points in $(0,1)^2$ according to the standard uniform distribution $\mathrm{U}(0,1).$ Then generate and superpose a set of $S$ curves $\phi_S(x)=\exp\bigg(\frac{\log^2 S}{\log x}\bigg)$ for $x\in(0,1).$ To begin this process, set the cardinality $|N|=|S|=9$ so we have $S=\big \lbrace 1/10,2/10,...,9/10\big\rbrace.$

How many pairs of curves of $\phi_S(x)$ don't have any of the random points between them? And how do you estimate the ratio $R$, of these "empty sectors," $\mathfrak S_0,$ out of the total number of curves $|S|?$

Here's a diagram. There are $5$ empty sectors (I'm counting the $2$ extra sectors near the boundary) and there are $9$ total curves. So $R=5/9$.

[image]

I did some manual counting of these empty sectors and I got $R=5/9\approx .555$ and $R=44/99\approx .444$ and $R=75/199\approx .377$ which shows that there's some variation. Without being able to run large simulations of this I had to come up with a heuristic. I computed a naïve estimate of the expected value of $R$ i.e. $(.555+.444+.377)/3\approx .459$.

I think that the following theoretical calculation gives the exact value of $R$:

$$ R=\lim_{|S|\to \infty}\frac{1}{|S|}\sum_{s \in S}\int_{(0,1)} \phi_S(x)~dx\approx.472772 $$

which says that to compute $R$ you don't have to manually count each empty sector one at a time, you just have to average the areas under the curves.

I'd like to see other approaches and see if they yield the same value for $R$. Part of me thinks the answer is just $R=1/2$.

> How do you precisely estimate the expected value of $R$ as $|S| \to \infty?$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of empty regions is a function of a multinomial random variable that counts the number of points in each region enclosed by sequential (adjacent) curves.  The multinomial weights are given by the area of each region (since the total area is unity).

Specifically, let $$\boldsymbol X = (X_0, X_1, \ldots, X_S) \sim \operatorname{Multinomial}(N, p_0, p_1, \ldots, p_S)$$ where $N$ is the number of points, $S$ is the number of curves, and for each $k \in \{0, 1, \ldots, S\}$, $p_k \in (0,1)$ are the probability parameters that describe the chance of a randomly placed point being inside the region enclosed by the curves $\phi_k(x)$ and $\phi_{k+1}(x)$, where $$\phi_k(x) = \exp\left(\frac{\log^2 \frac{k}{S+1}}{\log x}\right), \quad 0 < x < 1.$$  Note that we take $\phi_0$ to be the lower left boundary of the square and $\phi_{S+1}$ to be the upper right boundary, namely $$\phi_0 = \lim_{k \to 0^+} \phi_k, \quad \phi_{S+1} = \lim_{k \to 1^-} \phi_k.$$  Then define the variable $$Y = \frac{1}{S+1} \sum_{k=0}^S \mathbb 1 (X_k = 0).$$  This is the proportion of regions that contain no points.

The expectation of $Y$ is, by linearity
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[Y] &= \frac{1}{S+1} \sum_{k=0}^S \operatorname{E}[\mathbb 1 (X_k = 0)] \\
&= \frac{1}{S+1} \sum_{k=0}^S \Pr[X_k = 0] \\
&= \frac{1}{S+1} \sum_{k=0}^S (1 - p_k)^N.
\end{align}$$

since the probability that $X_k = 0$ is the *binomial* probability that out of $N$ independent Bernoulli trials, no points were placed in the $k^{\rm th}$ region, and the probability that a point misses is simply $1 - p_k$.

All that remains is the compute the probability parameters, namely

$$p_k = \int_{x=0}^1 \phi_{k+1}(x) - \phi_k(x) \, dx,$$

again using the earlier conventions for $\phi_0$ and $\phi_{S+1}$.  These are not expressible in elementary closed form, but can be numerically computed to sufficiently high precision.  For instance, with $S = 9$ and $N = 9$, we have

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
k & p_k & \Pr[X_k = 0] \\
\hline
 0 & 0.0289592 & 0.767604 \\
 1 & 0.0706443 & 0.517175 \\
 2 & 0.100001 & 0.387416 \\
 3 & 0.120655 & 0.314365 \\
 4 & 0.133605 & 0.27507 \\
 5 & 0.138969 & 0.260116 \\
 6 & 0.136199 & 0.267747 \\
 7 & 0.123843 & 0.304254 \\
 8 & 0.0985154 & 0.39321 \\
 9 & 0.0486086 & 0.638606 \\
\end{array}$$

which gives us $$\operatorname{E}[Y] \approx 0.412556.$$  Your calculation is off because if you include both the lower and upper boundaries (as you must, since these regions are also inside the unit square), the denominator is $10$, not $9$.  Moreover, knowing that the regions do not have areas expressible in elementary closed form, and they do not even have the same area, the answer is unlikely to be a rational number.

The limiting behavior depends on the choice of $N$ and $S$ and how they increase relative to each other.  If $N = S$, then some numerical computations show that $\operatorname{E}[Y]$ decreases as $S$ increases, which at least suggests that it is not $1/2$.

Comment: Is it likely that when $N=S$ and as $N,S \to \infty$ then $E[Y]=1/e$?

Comment: Correct me if wrong but aren't the regions expressible as modified Bessel functions of the second kind, $K_1$? And I agree the answer is unlikely to be a rational number

Comment: @JohnZimmerman Yes, they are expressible as Bessel functions, but those are not considered **elementary** functions.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function